# Azure API Management - Remove cache entry using wildcard

Tags: azure-api-management

I am currently caching response for an operation using the path of the request as the cache key. The path uses a route parameter and this was the simplest way of vary the cache entry using that route paratmer.

Store statement

```
<cache-store-value key="@(context.Request.Url.Path)" value="@(context.Response.Body.As<String>(preserveContent: true))" duration="86400" />
```

Get from cache

```
<cache-lookup-value key="@(context.Request.Url.Path)" variable-name="cachedResponse" />
```

I am trying to find a way to to purge any cache entries that have this path without the route parameter.

Example:

Cache is stored using keys:

```
/getsomething/1
/getsomething/2
/getsomething/3
```

How can I clear all the cache entries that have a key of /getsomething/* ?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No way to do that at once targeting only this subset of cached entries

For internal cache - cache will be purged if

1. You Make ANY change to the policy (this will purge all the entries)
2. Cache-Remove-Value policy (You need to know the cache keys)
3. TTL .... (Time to live) Expiry
4. Any Updates/Reboots (this will purge all the entries)

**Update**

You can try a mix of cache remove policy inside retry policy with a policy expression to increase a counter stored in a variable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#Retry

Comment: Is there anyway to iterate on a collection of cache entries? i havent been unable to find anything that would work.

Comment: You can try a mix of cache remove policy inside retry  policy with a policy expression to increase a counter stored in a variable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#Retry